# Bluetooth is not detected by Ubuntu 20.04. "dmesg | grep -i blue" and "lsusb | grep Bluetooth" don't output anything

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, hp

I have recently dual-booted my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and Bluetooth is not working. I am able to use it in Windows though.
The Bluetooth settings page in Ubuntu says: 
`No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth`

`dmesg | grep -i blue` and `lsusb | grep` don't return any output.

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56c9 IMC Networks HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Please help

Edit:
Computer: HP Laptop 15t-dw100
Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b1 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5009 (rev 01)
```

Comment: Could you [edit your question] to include the following details: (1) the brand & model of your computer (2) the output of `lspci`. With this information, it will be much easier to provide some specific suggestions on how to get bluetooth working with your device 

Comment: From what I've seen over the last couple of years, the RTL8821CE does not let a person use WiFi and Bluetooth at the same time within Linux. When WiFi is active, Bluetooth cuts out. You may need to find a compatible USB Bluetooth dongle, such as one from Kensington 

Comment: Oh :( Thanks anyways. Now I just hope Windows 11 will be good and freely upgradeable from Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Finally problem solved.
The problem is with the RTL8821CE chip as @matigo pointed out
Installing the [open-source driver](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce) by tomaspinho solved the Wi-Fi problem but Bluetooth still didn't work.
Running this solved the Bluetooth problem:

```
sudo modprobe btrtl
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
sudo bluetoothctl
>power on
```

Hope this is helpful for others.
If this didn't solve the problem I would suggest going through the [closed issues related to Bluetooth](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues?q=bluetooth%20is%3Aclosed) at tomaspinho's RTL8821CE GitHub repo.

Comment: This is really weird. After trying this I can't pair the device any more